# Indy SSL to plain socket pump

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I have to provide an SSL front for a plain TCP server, so I'm making a "pump" application that will provide an SSL connection to the outside while the original server can stay plain.

I'm trying to use the Indy components to support my SSL needs, but I can't seem to get any data from the SSL port. I assigned the TIdTCPServer.OnExecute to the following event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
 c:TIdTCPClient;
 cs,ss:TIdIOHandler;
 b:TBytes;
begin
 c:=TIdTCPClient.Create(Self);
 try
   c.Host:='127.0.0.1';
   c.Port:=60675;
   c.ConnectTimeout:=500;
   c.Connect;
   ss:=c.IOHandler;
   cs:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler;
   while (cs.Connected) and (ss.Connected) do
    begin
     if cs.CheckForDataOnSource(1) then
      begin
       try
        cs.ReadBytes(b,1,False);
       except on e:Exception do
        Memo1.Lines.Add(e.Message); //BAD out of Thread context
       end;
       if Length(b)>0 then
        ss.Write(b);
      end;
     if ss.CheckForDataOnSource(1) then
      begin
       ss.ReadBytes(b,1,False);
       if Length(b)>0 then
        cs.Write(b);
      end;
    end;
 finally
   c.Free;
 end;
end;
```

The TCP server has an SSL handler attached. I did the same on a plain HTTP server and it worked fine, so I'm assuming my SSL setup is not the issue.

cs=Client Side (the server socket) and ss=Server side (the client for the TCP server I'm trying to add SSL to).

Now, I know it needs cleanup and doing 1ms waits isn't pretty, but before I can attack that issue, I'd like to receive some data.

Neither of my ReadBytes get called. When I used `cs.Readable()`, I get `true` just once, but I still couldn't read.

What can I do to make a pump? Why am I not getting data?

Comment: I figured out my issue: My SSL port was working in PassThrough mode. I didn't know I had to set it myself in the OnConnect handler.

Comment: You must be using Indy 10 then. In Indy 9 and earlier, the server-side SSL IOHandler forced all accepted connections to be encrypted (PassThrough=False) even before any data was exchanged. That prevented things like mixed SSL/non-SSL clients, STARTTLS-style commands, etc. In Indy 10, the server-side SSL IOHandler now accepts new connections unencrypted (PassThrough=True) so you can pick which clients use SSL and when to activate SSL.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `TIdMappedPortTCP` component instead of `TIdTCPServer` directly.  `TIdMappedPortTCP` handles all the work of passing data back and forth between a client and another server.  By default, the outbound connection to the second server is not encrypted, even if the inbound connection to `TIdMappedPortTCP` is encrypted.

Comment: I need to inspect the data. The port is forwarded to one of a few servers, depending on the data that's received. It's not just a straight pump. I have to "Peek" before connecting to the client. Besides that, this would be a great way to do it. I'll look at the source for the `TIdMappedPortTCP` component and see how I should be doing it, though. I was thinking of using winsock select myself because I don't know exactly how to do it in Indy. But I'm assuming I'll find that answer int he source for `TIdMappedPortTCP`. Thanks! I see your name all through the Indy code. Nice work!

Comment: If you only need to "peek" the first bytes of a connection, you can do that in the `OnConnect` event and then dynamically adjust the `Host`/`Post` of the `TIdTCPClient` that `TIdMappedPortTCP` connects with after the event handler exits.