# Delphi Redirect SSL tcp data to other port no ssl

Tags: delphi, redirect, delphi-5, indy-9

I am working with D5 ( thats a fact ). I have Indy9 installed.
I'm trying to receive data of `IdMappedPortTCP` on port 8041 (SSL) and redirect the data to a `Tserversocket` on port 8040. So I will have support of SSL over `Tserversocket`.

I use the following code:

```
var
  masterdir:String;
begin
  masterdir:=Extractfilepath(paramstr(0));
  IdMappedPortTCP1.Active:=false;

  datamodule2.IdMappedPortTCP1.MappedHost:='192.168.0.3';
  datamodule2.IdMappedPortTCP1.MappedPort:=8041;
  datamodule2.IdMappedPortTCP1.DefaultPort:=8040;

  IdServerIOHandlerSSL1.SSLOptions.RootCertFile:=masterdir+'mycert.pem';
  IdServerIOHandlerSSL1.SSLOptions.CertFile:=masterdir+'mycert.pem';
  IdServerIOHandlerSSL1.SSLOptions.KeyFile:=masterdir+'key.pem';
  IdMappedPortTCP1.IOHandler:=IdServerIOHandlerSSL1;
  IdMappedPortTCP1.Active:=true;
end;
```

If I don't use SSL everything is fine. But when I use SSL teh request never comes to the port 8040 encrypted and I need it not encrypted so I can proccess it.

Comment: i think the answer to my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707429/indy-ssl-to-plain-socket-pump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your description whether `TServerSocket` is using SSL on port 8040 or not.  It makes a big difference in how you set up `TIdMappedPortTCP`.  However, from your description, you have the `MappedPort` and `DefaultPort` property assignments backwards, at least.  `DefaultPort` is the port that `TIdMappedPortTCP` listens on, so it should be 8041.  `MappedPort` is the port that `TIdMappedPortTCP` connects to, so it should be 8040.

It is not common to have unencrypted and encrypted connections on the same port.  Most protocols use separate ports.  Is that the case here?  Is port 8040 unencrypted, and port 8041 encrypted?

If you want `TIdMappedPortTCP` to accept encrypted and unencrypted clients on separate ports, you need to add 2 entries to the `TIdMappedPortTCP.Bindings` collection, one for each port, and not use the `DefaultPort` property at all.  In the `TIdMappedPortTCP.OnConnect` event, you can detect which port the client connected to, and then configure the `AThread.OutboundClient` accordingly before it connects to `TServerSocket`.

It is not wise to have unencrypted and encrypted clients connect to the same port.  In that scenario, you have to sniff the first few bytes to know if the client is sending an SSL handshake or not, and then act accordingly.  It is easier to just use separate ports instead.  However, some protocols do allow a client to connect to an unencrypted port and then send a command to activate encryption when needed.  In that scenario, you would only need 1 port in `TIdMappedPortTCP`, so you can either define 1 `Binding` or use `DefaultPort`.

`TIdMappedPortTCP` is primarily intended to be a straight passthrough of raw bytes back and forth between the client and the target server.  If `TServerSocket` is using SSL and you want the client to talk to `TServerSocket` using SSL *properly*, you should not be using `TIdServerIOHandlerSSL` at all.  Let `TIdMappedPortTCP` pass the client's raw encrypted data as-is to `TServerSocket`, and vice versa.  They should establish a secure session with each other, not with you.  This is especially important if either one of them performs peer identity validation.

If you need to process encrypted data that is being exchanged between the client and `TServerSocket`, you have to decrypt and re-encrypt the data as it passes through `TIdMappedPortTCP` (which means you are acting as a man-in-the-middle attacker, which peer validation is meant to prevent).  To do that, you have to establish separate SSL sessions between the client and `TIdMappedPortTCP`, and between `TIdMappedPortTCP` and `TServerSocket`.  Assigning a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSL` to `TIdMappedPortTCP` only facilitates the session with the client. You have to manually setup a session with `TServerSocket`.  To do that, you have to manually assign a new `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` object to the `AThread.OutboundClient.IOHandler` property in the `OnConnect` event.  `TIdMappedPortTCP` will not handle that for you.

If, however, `TServerSocket` is not using SSL, and you are using `TIdMappedPortTCP` as an SSL gateway into `TServerSocket`, then you can skip the `OutboundClient.IOHandler` assignment, since you would only need 1 SSL session, between `TIdMappedPortTCP` and the client.

Now, with that said, there are some problems in Indy 9. The `TIdSSLIOHandlerOpenSSL.PassThrough` property is False by default (thus assuming encryption is initially active), and `TIdServerIOHandlerSSL` assumes that *every* accepted client connection is using SSL, even if it really is not.  If an *unencrypted* client connects to `TIdMappedPortTCP` with `TIdServerIOHandlerSSL` assigned, the client will not be handled correctly.  These issues were fixed in Indy 10.  But in Indy 9, you will not be able to handle encrypted and unencrypted clients in the same `TIdMappedPortTCP` component.  If you are only dealing with encrypted clients though, you won't run into a problem.  Otherwise, create 2 `TIdMappedPortTCP` components, one listening on an unencrypted port, the other listening on an encrypted port.  They can share the same event handlers. If needed, you can use the `AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port` property to know which port the client is connected to.

Comment: as i said Tserversocket cannot handle SSL from default. So i thougt the tryck to recive data on a component that i can handle it and redirect them to Tserversocket port . Port 8040 is not using SSL
Default port Wich i listen for connections is 8040 ( SSL port) and i want to redirect them to Port 8041  My example is clear i think. Thanks for yoru answer but you dont help me. thanks any way